# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too large frame: 5211883372140375593

Tags: spark-submit

I submitted my code to the cluster to run, but I encountered the following error.

'''
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too large frame: 5211883372140375593
at org.sparkproject.guava.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:119)
at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.decodeNext(TransportFrameDecoder.java:148)

'''

and my submit command is like this

> spark-submit 
> --master spark://172.16.244.8:6066 
> --deploy-mode cluster 
> --num-executors 3 
> --executor-cores 8 
> --executor-memory 16g 
> --driver-memory 2g 
> --conf spark.default.parallelism=10 
> --class ParallelComputing 
> hdfs://172.16.244.5:9000/qlt/portrait-batch-0.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar

what is the reason

Comment: I've got the exception when I tried to use REST submission protocol against the regular `7077` port (not `6066`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is because the version of spark does not match the version of the cluster, which can be solved by modifying the local spark version to be consistent with the cluster.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Kubernetes and facing this same issue. Can you please share more detailed answer

Comment: @AtulSinghRajpoot - facing same issue , did u get any solution

Comment: I am facing the same issue on Kubernetes.

Answer (score 1):

In my spark project I face this same issue ,I found my spark version is 3.3.1 and hadoop version(hadoop-client-runtime) is 3.3.2. So I change my hadoop-client-runtime version from 3.3.2 to 3.3.1. After I tested, the problem was solved.