# Spark error when getting submission status: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too large frame: 5135603447297880359

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark

When I try to execute following command to get submission status:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --master spark://master:7077 --status driver-20210608160650-0012
```

Or:

```
curl http://master:7077/v1/submissions/status/20210608160650-0012
```

I receive strange error on master node:

```
21/06/08 16:12:41 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from /172.19.0.5:46734
master_1    | java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too large frame: 5135603447297880359
master_1    |   at org.sparkproject.guava.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:119)
master_1    |   at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.decodeNext(TransportFrameDecoder.java:148)
master_1    |   at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:98)
master_1    |   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
master_1    |   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
master_1    |   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
master_1    |   at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
master_1    |   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
master_1    |   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
master_1    |   at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
master_1    |   at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
master_1    |   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
master_1    |   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
master_1    |   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
master_1    |   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
master_1    |   at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
master_1    |   at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
master_1    |   at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
master_1    |   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Job itself was submitted and executed successfully:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --master spark://master:7077 \
--conf spark.standalone.submit.waitAppCompletion=true \
--name arrow-spark \
--class com.tasks.Task \
--deploy-mode cluster \
/path/to/my.jar
```

The only clue I've found was [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too large frame: 5211883372140375593](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64061652/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-too-large-frame-5211883372140375593) but it didn't work for me

Comment: Maybe this answer helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64061652/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-too-large-frame-5211883372140375593

Comment: @gerstams, I mentioned it in my question. Unfortunately, it didn't help

Comment: Sorry, missed it! I didn't find much else unfortunately :-(